# How to change position of items in RecyclerView programmatically?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, linearlayoutmanager

Is there a way to move a specific item to a specific position in `RecyclerView` using `LinearLayoutManager` programmatically?

Comment: Is updating the dataset an option?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this:

**Some Activity/Fragment/Whatever:**

```
List<String> dataset = new ArrayList<>();
RecyclerView recyclervSomething;
LinearLayoutManager lManager;
MyAdapter adapter;

//populate dataset, instantiate recyclerview, adapter and layoutmanager

recyclervSomething.setAdapter(adapter);
recyclervSomething.setLayoutManager(lManager);

adapter.setDataset(dataset);
```

**MyAdapter:**

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private List<String> dataset;
    public MyAdapter() {}
    //implement required methods, extend viewholder class...

    public void setDataset(List<String> dataset) {
        this.dataset = dataset;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    // Swap itemA with itemB
    public void swapItems(int itemAIndex, int itemBIndex) {
        //make sure to check if dataset is null and if itemA and itemB are valid indexes.
        String itemA = dataset.get(itemAIndex);
        String itemB = dataset.get(itemBIndex);
        dataset.set(itemAIndex, itemB);
        dataset.set(itemBIndex, ItemA);

        notifyDataSetChanged(); //This will trigger onBindViewHolder method from the adapter.
    }
}
```

Comment: How could I do this with animation ? For example, moving item at position n to top of the list ?

Comment: If you want an animation for just moving the elements you can use   `Collections.swap(this.mListItems, oldIndex, index);
notifyItemMoved(oldIndex, newIndex)`